# My server API calls for dynamic file routes working on localhost but not on vercel

Tags: vercel, next.js13

This is my directory in API

[image]

Performing this server call is successfully accessing file [searchtext].js

```
const result=await fetch('/api/user/films/autosearch/'+searchText,{
method:'GET',
headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',  }
```

But when I try to access the slug like so

```
const result=await fetch('/api/user/films/autosearch/1/'+props.amount,{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});
```

It's working on localhost and accessing file [...slug].js but not on vercel. I'm getting a json error on vercel only. Anyone knows why?